# How to redirect output to file instead of printing on screen and run a python code, all in background?

Tags: python, printing, output, tail

the following is my small python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(0,10000):
     print (i**2)
```

To run this code, I type the following in terminal on Ubuntu:

```
(time python trial_tail.py) & > trial_haha.t &
```

This does not write the output to file named trial_haha.t and prints it on screen.
How do I make it write to file instead of on screen and run it in the background?

Thanks
Abhinav

Comment: did you try $(time python trial_tail.py > trial_haha.t) & ?

Comment: Thanks, this writes the output to file. However at the end it writes the time taken on screen and waits for me hit enter. How do I avoid that?

Comment: redirect both stdout and stderr by doing &> instead of > ; I don't understand why it waits for enter at the end

Comment: Adding &> has the same old result. Can I somehow write the time taken to the output file as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
{ time python trial_tail.py ; } &> trial_haha.t &
```